# How can I make the batch file wait until another batch file completes execution?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, scripting

How can I make a batch file wait until another batch file has finished?

For example, I have:

```
echo hi >r.txt
echo some piece of code >>r.txt 

start ar.bat

echo some piece of code >>ar.txt
```

I want the code after `start ar.bat` to execute only after `ar.bat` finishes executing. I tried without `start` and it works, but I want to run `ar.bat` in a separate window.

Is there any method to check whether `ar.bat` has finished?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `call ar.bat` to do it completely with batch file commands.

Use `start /wait ar.bat` to get another window and wait for it to complete.

Comment: Use `call` - invoking another batch file directly (without `call`) won't return from the 2nd batch file (it's more of a jump than a call in that case).