# Can you fork in Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to start two programs from the batch file, (also batch files) - they will execute few seconds. Then in the main batch file I want to wait while both are finished and then continue main execution. Is that possible at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572176/how-to-make-the-batch-file-wait-until-another-batch-file-completes-execution

Comment: @DmitriyBotov: That's for *one* batch file only, though. They want to run two simultaneously and only continue execution when *both* have stopped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can, sort of:

```
@echo off
set Token=MAIN_%RANDOM%_%CD%
start "%Token%_1" cmd /c child1.cmd
start "%Token%_2" cmd /c child2.cmd
:loop
ping -n 2 localhost >nul 2>nul
tasklist /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq %Token%_1" | findstr "cmd" >nul 2>nul && set Child1=1 || set Child1=
tasklist /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq %Token%_2" | findstr "cmd" >nul 2>nul && set Child2=1 || set Child2=
if not defined Child1 if not defined Child2 goto endloop
goto loop
:endloop
echo Both children died.
```

`child1` and `child2` were just executing `pause`. This uses a more or less unique token to identify the child batch files. They are started in an own window with `start` and each one is given a specific window title. Using that window title we can find them again using `tasklist` and determine whether they are still running.

It gets a little tricky figuring out whether the batch files are still running. `tasklist` with the window title filter does what it's supposed to do, but it won't return a sensible errorlevel. That's why we have to pipe through `findstr` to pick up the process name (to avoid being language-sensitive by picking up the error message).

Comment: That works! do you know if it will still work as a scheduled task?