# Sqlplus wait until parallel scripts are finished to execute script

Tags: windows, batch-file, sqlplus

I have a batch file which looks like this, executing the scripts in parallel:

```
start sqlplus user/pwd@tnsid @myscript1.sql &
start sqlplus user/pwd@tnsid @myscript2.sql &
start sqlplus user/pwd@tnsid @myscript3.sql
```

What would be the way to wait until the three of them are finished and then execute yet another command:

```
sqlplus user/pwd@tnsid @myscript4.sql
```

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20698394/409172) help?

Answer (score 0):

From what i know from powershell, there is a parameter for the "Start-Process" command named "-wait" which essentially first executes the command given and only when finished proceeds.
Documentation to said command:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/wait-process?view=powershell-7.3
example:
Start-Process -wait <process_to_execute>

knowing that i searched for an equal in windows-batch and i found something like this:
start /B /wait cmd /c "Path"

source:
https://www.delftstack.com/howto/batch/batch-file-wait-for-command-to-finish/#use-wait-to-wait-for-a-command-to-finish-execution

So in your case i wonder if something along the line of this works:
start /WAIT &....
(note: from what i can guess, you will have to probably add the "/WAIT" to every of the first three scripts, but i am not sure about that since the example only provided one such command in each example.)

and afterwards execute script4.sql